# Rewrite matrix operation involving diagonal matrix and Kronecker product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, kronecker-product

$D$ is a diagonal matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{(kn) \times (kn)}$, $W$ is in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$. Does there exist a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ so that $D (W \otimes I_{k}) = A \otimes I_{k}$?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What exactly is not clear to you? What did you try and where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried to write $D$ as kronecker product/ sum of kronecker products, e.g. $D = Q \otimes I_{k}$ (which is not possible given the arbitrary value of $D$), or $D = \sum_i Q_i \otimes I_{k}$ - which also does not seem to work... I also tried to use $D$ to "modify" $W$ first - but still have not gotten a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so as you write in the comments, you know that there are some $D$ which cannot be written as a Kronecker product. Now if we take $m = n$ and $W = I_n$, we'll get a counterexample.

Comment: Got it, many thanks!